# Linked Server From SQL 2008 R2 to MS Access

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, odbc, oledb

Does anyone know where I can find the drivers to create a linked server from SQL 2008 R2 to a MS Access database (accdb).  I have searched through the Microsoft site for the old Jet drivers and could not find them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the best you can do these days.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

*This download will install a set of components that facilitate the transfer of data between existing Microsoft Office files such as Microsoft Office Access 2010 (*.mdb and *.accdb) files and Microsoft Office Excel 2010 (*.xls, *.xlsx, and *.xlsb) files to other data sources such as Microsoft SQL Server. Connectivity to existing text files is also supported. ODBC and OLEDB drivers are installed for application developers to use in developing their applications with connectivity to Office file formats.*

Comment: I downloaded and installed that already but I don't see anything Access/Jet listed in my providers list

Comment: Some "hints" for you. Its been 5 years since I messed with it... there is a reason.  I don't know much about what you're asking..just trying to help  https://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/with-database-password/  https://granadacoder.wordpress.com/2010/12/07/bug-in-documentation-microsoft-access-database-engine-2010-redistributable/

Comment: I hate access.  This is a legacy system that I have to draw some data from for a while.  I think the issue is that I need to install the x64 version of the DB Engine files but it will not let me since I do not have x64 office products on the server.

Comment: This fixed my issue btw
https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad-civil-3d/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/How-to-install-64-bit-Microsoft-Database-Drivers-alongside-32-bit-Microsoft-Office.html

Comment: That's a nice hack...could have helped me a few years ago.  I would take the relevant parts of that article and paste/append your original post, so it doesn't become a dead link in the future.